# Multiple comparison of non-normal, heteroscedastic data. What test should I use?

Tags: r, nonparametric, multiple-comparisons, heteroscedasticity

I have a set of brain pathology data. These were obtained by counting certain parameters in the brain. Due to availability of human brains, the amount of cases vary a lot across the different groups of my cohort (5, 17, 65). I need to compare the results obtained for the different groups.

I followed these steps to analyse the data using R:

I tested the counts in the individual groups of the cohort for normality using Shapiro-Wilk test, obtaining tiny p-values.

I tested the homoscedasticity across the groups using Levene's test, obtaining a very small p-value.

Having these groups which have very different distributions in terms of pathology, and which present big differences in variance, I'm stuck and I don't know which test I should use.

I thought of using one-way ANOVA with Welch correction `oneway.test()`, but apparently this doesn't account for non-normality.

Which test should I use and which post-hoc test should follow it?